# Dynamically color labels in color of features (QGIS 3.x)

Tags: labeling, qgis-3

How do I dynamically color labels in the color of the labeled feature? 
As you can see in the screenshot, the lines are in different colors, but the labels are just in black. As I know, I have to set the label color manually to get my expected result. But is there also a dynamic way to do so? Surely there is, because it‘s QGIS! But I don‘t know how. Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the following expression at the label color:

```
@symbol_color
```

[image]

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: QGIS rocks again and again!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work when your layer have implemented the geometry generator. Or am I doing something wrong?